# Why is that when I have a device already mounted, I am unable to mount other devices in Linux?

Tags: mount, ubuntu-12.04

I am running Ubuntu LTS 12.04 and I have mounted an ISO image to the `/media` directory. The command I used to `mount` is `mount -t iso9660 -o loop,ro name_of_iso.iso /media`.

1. Am I correct to refer to it as a device although is a locally mounted image?
2. Why is that when I attempt to attach an external harddrive, I get the message that it is unable to mount as there is already another device mounted?
3. Why does Ubuntu create a new directory for it as it generally would?
4. How does Ubuntu automatically create a directory that reflects the name of the device which it then mounts to?
5. Does it mean that if I want to mount multiple devices manually i.e. by running the `mount` command I would need to create directories in the `/media` directory?

Comment: (1) No, you *mount* a filesystem, not a device. (3) This makes no sense.  (5) Yes, or try using the `/mnt` directory instead of `/media` when manually using the *mount* command.

Comment: @sawdust - Thanks. So even if I have attached a device such as an external harddrive, I would be mounting a filesystem? Why does (3) not make sense? Each time I attach an external harddrive or USB stick/pen, Ubuntu appears to create a directory I can access e.g. `/media/{name_of_device}`. What difference does it make if I use `/mnt` or `/media`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The command I used to mount is
>            mount -t iso9660 -o loop,ro name_of_iso.iso /media.

You mounted a read-only filesystem.
That would inhibit any further mounts by the *automount*, since it can no longer create mount-points in the `/media` directory.

(1) No, you mount a filesystem, not a device.
(2) You made `/media` a read-only directory.
(3) This makes no sense.  Do you mean "Why *doesn't* Ubuntu create a new directory for it as it normally would?  See reply for (2).
(4) That's the job of the *automount* daemon.
(5) Yes, or try using the `/mnt` directory instead of `/media` when manually using the *mount* command.  Leave `/media` alone for the *automount* daemon.

> So even if I have attached a device such as an external harddrive, I would be mounting a filesystem?

*mount* is provided the filename where the filesystem is located.  The filesystem can be in a file (e.g. ISO image file), a hard drive partition, or a (local or remote) directory (e.g. NFS).

Try an experiment: wipe the hard drive clean, and then try to mount it.  It will not work; *mount* simply won't deal with a device.  The HDD has to be partitioned and then a filesystem has to be created in the partition before that partition can be mounted.  The entire "external harddrive" cannot be mounted, as there is no filesystem encompassing the whole drive.